# Android How to save cookies on sdcard using HttpClient

Tags: android, http, cookies

I need to know a way to store my HttpClient cookieStore on a txt file as a string and how to re-use those and make a new httpConnection.

```
    httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    localContext= new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

Comment: I really want to know the answer to this

Comment: Solution and simple example are explained here:
https://github.com/augustopicciani/HttpClient-save-cookies-to-file